# Adding last values to the legends in AmCharts Graph

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is there a way to add last values in the graph to the legend names when not hover over the AmCharts graph ?

Here is a code pen with a demo chart.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LxmLaL

Here is the js code

```
    var chartData = generateChartData();

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "legend": {
         "periodValueText":"last"
    },
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "synchronizeGrid":true,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id":"v1",
        "axisColor": "#FF6600",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "axisAlpha": 1,
        "position": "left"
    }, {
        "id":"v2",
        "axisColor": "#FCD202",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "axisAlpha": 1,
        "position": "right"
    }, {
        "id":"v3",
        "axisColor": "#B0DE09",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "offset": 50,
        "axisAlpha": 1,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "valueAxis": "v1",
        "lineColor": "#FF6600",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
        "hideBulletsCount": 30,
        "title": "red line",
        "valueField": "visits",
        "fillAlphas": 0
    }, {
        "valueAxis": "v2",
        "lineColor": "#FCD202",
        "bullet": "square",
        "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
        "hideBulletsCount": 30,
        "title": "yellow line",
        "valueField": "hits",
        "fillAlphas": 0
    }, {
        "valueAxis": "v3",
        "lineColor": "#B0DE09",
        "bullet": "triangleUp",
        "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
        "hideBulletsCount": 30,
        "title": "green line",
        "valueField": "views",
        "fillAlphas": 0
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {},
    "chartCursor": {
        "cursorPosition": "mouse"
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "axisColor": "#DADADA",
        "minorGridEnabled": true
    }
});

chart.addListener("dataUpdated", zoomChart);
zoomChart();


// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
    var chartData = [];
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 100);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // we create date objects here. In your data, you can have date strings
        // and then set format of your dates using chart.dataDateFormat property,
        // however when possible, use date objects, as this will speed up chart rendering.
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

        var visits = Math.round(Math.sin(i * 5) * i);
        var hits = Math.round(Math.random() * 80) + 500 + i * 3;
        var views = Math.round(Math.random() * 6000) + i * 4;

        chartData.push({
            date: newDate,
            visits: visits,
            hits: hits,
            views: views
        });
    }
    return chartData;
}

function zoomChart(){
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 20, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

I believe it has something to do with [periodValueText](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#periodValueText) but  I'm unable to figure out how to achieve the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have correctly pointed out that [`periodValueText`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#periodValueText) needs to be used. You just need to use double-bracketed meta codes in it. For close value it's `[[value.close]]`:

```
"legend": {
  "periodValueText":"[[value.close]]"
}
```

Comment: But I really dont understand what is '[[value.close]]'. If I modify it to [[value.close]] it simply prints it .....

Comment: It works for me. Did you include the quotes? It should be a string.